# Successfully Installed PIL, also ImportError: cannot import name 'imread' from 'scipy.misc'

Tags: python

I'm new to python. 'from scipy.misc import imread' gives me an 'ImportError' even I have Successfully installed Pillow.

--> pip install Pillow

Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in 
***\lib\site-packages (6.0.0)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from scipy.misc import imread
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'imread' from 'scipy.misc'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a version problem. I replaced `scipy.misc` with `imageio`.

```
`imread` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
Use `imageio.imread` instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed **Pillow** with **scipy**, this will happen.
try with installing **scipy** 1.1.0,

```
pip install scipy==1.1.0
```

this works for me.